# Geometry find area of triangle with no measurements

Tags: geometry, triangles

We have a triangle inside a square which has four smaller squares. The base of the triangle divides one of the smaller squares in half. The tip of the triangle is one corner of the bigger square. Without knowing the measurements, how can we discover which fraction of the big square is comprised of the triangle?

Comment: The hypothesis are not clear. Call $ABCD$ the square and (I guess) $O$ its center and $E$, $F$, $G$, $H$ the mid-points of the sides (respectively) $AB$, $BC$, $CD$, $AD$. Call $\triangle UVW$ the triangle which satisfies... what?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A possible sketch of the triangle.

It has base $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}s$ and height $\displaystyle \frac{3}{4}s$, and thus has area $\displaystyle \frac{3}{16}s^2$.

The ratio of the triangle's area to the square's area is $\displaystyle \frac{\frac{3}{16}s^2}{s^2}=\frac{3}{16}$

Therefore, $\displaystyle \boxed{\frac{3}{16}}$ of the square is comprised of the triangle.